# Named anchor "s" doesn't work?

Tags: html, debugging, hyperlink, anchor

In a "table of contents"-ish area we see:

```
<tr>
<td><a href="#r">R</a></td>
<td><a href="#s">S</a></td>
<td><a href="#tu">T-U</a></td>
<td><a href="#v">V</a></td>
<td><a href="#wxyz">W-X-Y-Z</a></td>
</tr>
```

And then (somewhat predictably) we find this:

```
<h1 id="r"></h1>
-----something here having to do with "r"
<h1 id="s"></h1>
-----something here having to do with "s"
```

For some reason, the link "S" doesn't bring you to the empty header - any idea why??

Comment: Is there, perhaps, more than one element with an `id="s"` on the page (or, a `name="s"`)?

Comment: It would help to know which browser(s) you have tested. I had no problem with this on Chrome.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle that reproduces this issue? I have been unable to: http://jsfiddle.net/VVkcc/3/

Answer (score 3):

It should work unless it just appears as if it doesn't because your page might not have enough content to actually scroll down...

check it out in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tgfem/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the name attribute either along with or instead of ID attribute. Here is an example from [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp):

```
<a href="#C4">See also Chapter 4</a>
<h2><a name="C4">Chapter 4</a></h2>
```